# My sequence action does not work Swift Sprite Kit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have been trying to do this for a long time,what I am trying to do is make "bar1" move to the bottom of the screen then two seconds later, bar2 comes down then bar3 etc, my problem is that when I run my code all I see is bar1 moving down the screen I wait and nothing happens.

Here is my code:

```
    //
//  PlaysScene.swift
//  Pocket Rocket3
//
//  Created by Lucas Farleigh on 27/11/2014.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Lucas Farleigh. All rights reserved.
//

import spriteKit

class PlayScene:SKScene {
    //declaring the node in this scene!
    let background = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "background")

    let bar1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"bar1")

    let bar2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"bar2")

    let bar3 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"bar3")

    let bar4 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"bar4")

    let bar5 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed:"bar5")


    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        let delay = SKAction.waitForDuration(NSTimeInterval(2.5))
        let actionmove = SKAction.moveTo(CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),0), duration:13)
        let sequence = SKAction.sequence([actionmove ,delay])
        actionmove.timingMode = SKActionTimingMode.EaseOut
        var num1 = CGFloat(50)
        var num2 = 1
        bar2.runAction(sequence)
        bar1.runAction(sequence)
        bar3.runAction(sequence)
        addChild(bar2)
        addChild(bar3)
        addChild(bar4)
        addChild(bar5)




        actionmove.timingMode = SKActionTimingMode.EaseOut
            bar1.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),CGRectGetMaxY(self.frame))
        background.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame),CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))

        //doing the background stuff
        background.yScale = 2.0
        background.xScale = 3.0
        addChild(background)
                //doing the the bar stuff
         bar1.xScale = 2.5
       addChild(bar1)
        println("hello!!!!")


}


    override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {



    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I don't see you adding `bar1` to your scene at all, so make sure and do that.

The reason you only see one bar is that they all start in the same position, and they're all moving at the same speed at the same time. They are covering one another.

There's several ways to make them move in a sequence but one way is to use a completion block at the end of each action to call the next action.

```
addChild(bar1)
addChild(bar2)
addChild(bar3)

bar1.runAction(sequence, completion: {
    bar2.runAction(sequence, completion: {
        bar3.runAction(sequence)
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks only i wanted it to run the action a quarter way than the last action